# Centering with \includegraphics not with \begin{figure}?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I mess up with things when I try to use the figure-thing: the picture is not appearing with the correct alignment (apparently because I forget the `float` package). Now I want to use only the `graphicx` package with `\includegraphics`. How can I center the `\includegraphics` without figure?

Not working or doing centering to the document afterwards.

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5 \textwidth]{./Pictures/r.png}{\centering}
\includegraphics[width=0.5 \textwidth]{./Pictures/r.png}\centering
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Put `\includegraphics` into a `center` environment -- this also adds some space before and after your picture.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% "demo" to make example compilable without .png-file

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{mypicture.png}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The environment `center` puts some extra vertical space around its contents, which is frowned upon, at least for me. Therefore I prefer the command `\centering`, i.e. `{\centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{mypicture.png}}`, the outer pair of braces is to make the effect of `\centering` be local.

Comment: @tohecz I'd say `center` should be frowned upon inside floats (which add own space before/after them), but is perfectly fine for pictures inserted directly in the text.

Comment: @tohecz Your command misses a \par before the end of outer bracket. Without \par it won't work.

Comment: Neither the center environment nor centering appears to work for beamerposter. =/

Comment: \centering can cause trouble when you specify a rotation angle in a way that defining an environment using \begin{center}...\end{center} seems to avoid - however, if \centering is causing trouble, it can help to specify as follows: {\centering \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{mypicture.png} \par}

Answer (score 24):

`\includegraphics{..}` looks to TeX like a big letter, center it the same way

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{...}
\end{center}
```

or use `\centering` if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to center a includegraphic is to use \centerline:

```
\centerline{\includegraphics{...}}
```

I've no always managed to get centering to work for what ever reason.

Comment: You should be aware that `\centerline` is not a supported LaTeX command and that it has some subtleties. For instance, you want to use it only between blank lines.

Comment: I found it tends to work more often than \centering